# Content Script pattern patch confusion

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write my first chrome extension and I can't get the content script loading correctly. I would like it to load for only the home page of You Tube (ie, https://www.youtube.com/); however, I would not like it to load for any other page, for example, after a user searches (ie, https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=programming). Here is what I have:

```
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["*://*.youtube.com/*"], 
  "exclude_matches": ["*://*.youtube.com/"],
  "js": ["jquery.js", "content.js"]
}
```

]

Using the above code, content.js doesn't load at all; however, if I take out the "exclude_matches", the content script loads on https://www.youtube.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your manifest includes *all* of the youtube pages *except* the main page.

The following will include only the main page:

```js
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["*://www.youtube.com/"],
        "js": ["jquery.js", "content.js"]
    }
]
```

However Youtube uses history API navigation which means that if the user first opened a video page and then navigated to the main page your content script won't be injected automatically. You will need to use [chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onHistoryStateUpdated) event handler with [url filters](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#filtered):

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(
    function(details) {
        var tabId = details.tabId;
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "jquery.js", runAt: "document_start"}, function() {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "content.js", runAt: "document_start"});
        });
    },
    {
        url: [
            {urlEquals: "https://www.youtube.com/"}
        ]
    }
);
```

And you'll probably need a handler to remove the effect of your content scripts when user navigates from the main page. This can be implemented as a [pagehide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pagehide) listener in the content script or using (another) `onHistoryStateUpdated` listener.

Alternatively you can have your scripts on all of the youtube and then check whether current url is of the home page in the content script. This might be useful in case script injection with `onHistoryStateUpdated` happens too late and you see a delay between navigation and subsequent applying of content scripts.